# Loading panels from different files

Tags: netbeans-8

I am using netbeans to design my Gui app
I added a jframe with tabbed pane. For each tab, I created a Jpanel in its own Java file as I don't want everything in one file

So in the first jframe file, I modified the "custom code" so it uses the Jpanel I created. 
The problem is that the Jpanel is not shown when I run the program. I believe because the first file is sitting it's own layout and overwriting the layout of the Jpanel on the other file. I tried to remove the layout setting but it is generated code and not letting me do so. what do you say I should do to fix that?

Is there a way netbeans to tell it to load panel from another file? Or is There a way I can remove the layout setting from code generation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Can see both panels in the frame and didn't had to create any custom code.

- I Create a JFrame and both JPanels.
- In the JFrame inserted a Tabbed Pane.
- From the "Projects" window (usually in the top left side of the editor) dragged both JPanel to the JFrame (one at the time)

And when I run i can see both panels and all of its components.

Comment: Awesome the drag is what I was missing. I didnt know that you can drag things.